# Powershell wait until process completes running simultaneous processes

Tags: powershell, firebird, database-backups, 7zip

I have a powershell script that will kick off multiple instances of two different processes.

I want to be able to launch multiple simultaneous instances of gbak, and I don't want 7zip to start at all until the first instance of gbak finishes, and I want a new instance of 7zip to start each time an instance of gbak finishes.

Here is my script as it stands:

```
Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "USE ASPNETDB; SELECT DATABASELOCATION, SITEID FROM FIREBIRDCONNECTIONS;" -ServerInstance "DV-SQLSTAG01\EXPRESS2014" | Export-CSV - Path "C:\Scripts\strings.csv"
C:
CD C:\Scripts
$fbConn = Import-Csv -Path .\strings.csv
ForEach ($site in $fbConn) {
$cString = $site.DATABASELOCATION
$siteid = $site.SITEID
$backupDir = "D:\DBBackups"
$backupFile = "Cpib_$siteid.bak"
$gbak = ".\gbak.exe"
$gbakArgs = "-b -g -user sysdba -password masterkey $cString $backupDir\$backupFile"
$7zip = ".\7za.exe"
$7zArgs = "a -v1g -r -y -t7z -mx=3 $backupDir\CPIB_$siteid@$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd).7za $backupDir\$backupFile"
Start-Process $gbak $gbakArgs
Start-Process $7zip $7zArgs
}
```

What the application is doing now is launching all instances of gbak and 7zip at the same time, all at once. I can use a wait command after the start-process command for gbak, but then it will only launch one instance of gbak. I want it to have them all going at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sugguest you to work with *Jobs*. Use the [Start-Job](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx) cmdlet to start a new Job foreach of your sites. They will run in parallel so you can add the `-Wait`switch to the gbak process again. Finally, retrieve all Jobs using the [Get-Job](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113328) cmdlet and wait until they finish using [Wait-Job](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113422)

Comment: This appears to output a table with different jobs showing a State of "running" or "completed", but does not actually start either of these processes.

Comment: I missed the part with the parameters and edited my answer now, try again.

Comment: I'm getting the same result, only now instead of two running jobs and two completed, it just shows two completed. It still won't actually start the processes.

Comment: Okay, I removed my example because im not able to test the script. This should still answer your question.

Comment: It appears that Start-Job doesn't seem to work with gbak for some reason. I can use start-job with other executables just fine. I don't think I'll be able to use start-job in this script.